# Glide transition breaks transform

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-glide

I want to make rounded corners on my image with placeholder transition. 
(other SO answers are about rounded corners without translation, don't mark duplicate)

This code makes rounded corners:

```
Glide
    .with(itemView.context)
    .load(imgUrl)
    .transform(CenterCrop(), RoundedCorners(radius))
    .placeholder(R.drawable.default_image)
    .into(itemView.image)
```

This code doesn't make it (when I add transition):

```
Glide
    .with(itemView.context)
    .load(imgUrl)
    .transform(CenterCrop(), RoundedCorners(radius))
    .placeholder(R.drawable.default_image)
    .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions().crossFade()) // There
    .into(itemView.image)
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPD: image xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/cd_event_image"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    tools:srcCompat="@drawable/default_image" />
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me. I am getting both transition & rounded corners. Are you using this inside any recycler view/list view? Are you using the latest version of glide? *Edit* Is your issue: You are not getting placeholder image with rounded corner? If so, see this : https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/3448

Comment: @Priyabrata, I'm using it inside LinearLayout. Finally got rounded corners but how to make it transparent? (Now it's black)

Comment: Black as in? what made it black? the image view is black? @caxapexac

Comment: @Priyabrata, I see placeholder pic through round corners

Comment: In my example, my placeholder is not with round corner, the actual image that i am loading is with round corners.

Comment: In my example, my placeholder is not with round corner, the actual image that i am loading is with round corners.

Comment: https://imgur.com/9C6X6sW @Priyabrata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved using rounded corner shape placeholder instead of image (rectange of the placeholder hided rounded corner):

```
Glide
    .with(itemView.context)
    .load(imgUrl)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.shape_rounded)
    .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions().crossFade())
    .transform(RoundedCorners(radius))
    .into(itemView.image)
```

shape_rounded:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/event_corners_radius" />
    <solid android:color="@color/rdColorMainBackground"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: If placeholder is a special picture, then you have to set a shape_round for it. In this case, the number of shape_round files will be as much as the round(num) * placeholder picture(num). So it's not a good way to fix this question.